# Divide 2 integers (leetcode 29) - recursion issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm having issues when i need to do a count (or aggregation) in recursion problems, for eg. in this problem where i'm trying to divide 2 integers w/o using multiplication, division and mod operator.

```
 def divide(self, dividend: int, divisor: int) -> int:
        # pass
        # Edge cases removed for clarity

        count = 0
        resNeg = False

        origDivisor = divisor

        count = self.helper(dividend, divisor, origDivisor, 0)
        print(" count is -> ", count)

        return count


 def helper(self, dividend, divisor, origDivisor, count=0):

        while (dividend >= divisor):
            dividend = dividend - divisor
            count += (origDivisor // divisor)
            divisor *= divisor

        print(" count -> ", count)

        if(dividend > origDivisor):
            self.helper(dividend, origDivisor, origDivisor, count)
        else:
            return count
```

when i try to return count from helper function, it returns None,
instead - i want the code to return the count (eg. when dividend - 10, divisor = 3, count returned should be - 3)

Explanation on how i can re-structure recursion code to return the count would really be appreciated.
I seem to be getting stuck in similar recursion problems.

Pls. note - in the code above, i've removed code for edge cases, also it handles only +ve values of dividend/divisor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible problem is related to this logic:

```
if(dividend > origDivisor):
    self.helper(dividend, origDivisor, origDivisor, count)
else:
    return count
```

The `self.helper()` method returns a value which you've ignored.  Generally, if a recursive function returns a value, you have to deal with that value when you call it recursively.  I might have expected code more like:

```
if(dividend > origDivisor):
    return self.helper(dividend, origDivisor, origDivisor, count)

return count
```

But that doesn't solve all your problems.  You seem to be making this harder than necessary.  Here's a highly simplifed example that hopefully gives you some idea of how to approach this:

```
def divide(dividend, divisor):

    quotient = divide_recursive(dividend, divisor)

    return quotient

def divide_recursive(dividend, divisor, count=0):

    if dividend >= divisor:
        return divide_recursive(dividend - divisor, divisor, count + 1)

    return count

print(divide(125, 5))
```